# MIPS: Getting Values of Nodes in Linked List

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I have an assignment to clean up a linked list by "deleting" any nodes that contain a value less than a certain number (lets say 10). Its a bit more difficult than expected, since the nodes are not in order in memory. See below

```
list:
.word 15
.word n1

n2:
.word 12
.word n3

n6:
.word 27
.word n7

n3:
.word 22
.word n4

n1:
.word 1
.word n2

n5:
.word 34
.word n6

n7:
.word 6
.word  -1             # logical end of the list

n4:
.word 9
.word n5
```

If the head points to address "268500992", which contains 15, and the next location four bits away contains the pointer to the next node (called n1), how can I get the value from n1?

I have tried the following but it is loading an address (the pointer of the 1st node or address of n1) into $t0 instead of the value at that address.

```
la    $a0,list 
addi  $a0, $a0, 4
lw    $t0,0($a0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that `la $a0,list` will load a pointer to list. A subsequent `lw $t0,0($a0)` will load the value of the head node, and `lw $t0,4($a0)` (or the operation you did), will load the pointer to the next node. You are still is the head node, but now `$t0` points to the node 1. The best thing to do would be to use `lw $a0,4($a0)` to go to the next node. To retrieve its value you still need to do `lw $t0,0($a0)`.